# IE executes small-device ruled css media query

Tags: css, internet-explorer, media-queries

IE 6-7-8 (dunno 9) executes this css without respect to the media rule..

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 680px), only screen and (max-device-width: 680px)" href="styles/small-device.css" />
```

this one is ok:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 680px)" href="styles/small-device.css" />
```

Why?

In head i have this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because this media query is a CSS3 feature which is not fully supported by IE and especially IE6 (which has no support at all).

You should try conditional resource loading with browser sniffing.
Because IE6,7,8 are not used in small devices you could combine both. IE9 is used in WP7

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen"/>

<![endif]-->
<!--[if !(lte IE 8)]>
<style type="text/css" media="screen and (min-device-width: 450px)"/>

<![endif]-->
```

http://www.akademy.co.uk/blog/2010/03/css-style-ie6-media-hack/

Update: What I propose is that it is safe to use NON-small screen CSS safely for all IEs because they are not available on small screen devices.

If you want to use it for resized browsers, well that is not possible in IE unless you use jscript (dynamic properties) in your CSS. eg:

```
div {
  min-height: 300px;

  /* simulates min-height in IE6 */
  _height: expression(document.body.clientHeight < 300 ? "300px" : "auto");
}
```

Comment: Tnaks for your answer. Im just wondering why is the latter works and the above dont.  Btw I use modernizr, so if I use the working one, Its fine and functional in IE6-7 too.

Comment: IE should not apply styles for media it doesn't recognize, so your answer would seem out of place here.

Comment: well that is the idea! the second style will not apply because IE does not recognize it

Comment: The question is saying that it does, even though it shouldn't.

Comment: why exactly IE is confused is hard to tell. It is well known that IE parser is strange and have bugs. Probably the longer media rule is threated like wrong attribute and ignored which effectively removes it and the css loads always.